# Why does this recursion behave this way?

Tags: java

I'm learning about recursion and I ran this function to track the "count" variable to see how it changes while the recursion is going through. After getting 4 strings of "Hello." back after the count was already 0 I wanted to check what was happening to the count. I found that it was actually incrementing by one, but I don't know why it would. Why is the count incrementing after the count was already set at 0? Is it going back to its original value after terminating the recursion?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        sayHi(4);
    }

    public static void sayHi(int i) {
        int count = i;
        System.out.println(count);
        if(count == 0) return;


        System.out.println("hi!");
        sayHi(count - 1);

        System.out.println(count);

        System.out.println("Hello.");


    }
}
```

This is the output of the code:

```
OUTPUT: 

4
hi!
3
hi!
2
hi!
1
hi!
0
1
Hello.
2
Hello.
3
Hello.
4
Hello.
```

Comment: It's not incrementing, it's just printing the current value of `count` in that specific call-frame. I suggest you use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code, step into the recursive calls, and see what really happens.

Comment: First you get deeper and print decrementing numbers with each iteration. Then it goes back the call stack, continues function execution after the recursion point, and prints the "original" values of the parameter in reverse order

Comment: The value of `count` itself never changes, and each call to the method outputs the value twice.  *Between* those outputs is another call to the same method, which passes a value of one less than `count`.  In *that* method call, its own `count` never changes and outputs twice.  And so on.

Comment: The thing to keep in mind here is `sayHi` is invoked a total of 5 times, and each invocation will have its own independent `count` variable.

Comment: Remember that variables don't change unless you assign them.  `sayHi(count - 1)` does not change the value of `count`, because it is not assigned.  It does pass the *value* of `count-1` to the method, but that's all it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not incrementing, and in fact the value of `count` never changes at all.
It's just being output twice:

```
int count = i;
System.out.println(count); // <--- first here
if(count == 0) return;

System.out.println("hi!");
sayHi(count - 1);

System.out.println(count); // <--- then here
System.out.println("Hello.");
```

*In between* those two is where the recursion occurs.  So in the output:

```
4    // these
hi!  // are
3
hi!
2
hi!
1
hi!
0
1
Hello.
2
Hello.
3
Hello.
4      // the outermost
Hello. // method call
```

and:

```
4
hi!
3    // these
hi!  // are
2
hi!
1
hi!
0
1
Hello.
2
Hello.
3      // the second outermost
Hello. // method call
4
Hello.
```

Until:

```
4
hi!
3
hi!
2
hi!
1
hi!
0    // this is the innermost method call
1
Hello.
2
Hello.
3
Hello.
4
Hello.
```

There's nothing special about recursion, and new developers tend to very much over-think it.  The method itself doesn't do anything particularly complex.  Ignore for a moment that it's recursive and just examine what it does:

```
int count = i;                // declare a value, which never changes
System.out.println(count);    // output that value
if(count == 0) return;        // conditionally return (the innermost does this)

System.out.println("hi!");    // output a string
sayHi(count - 1);             // call a method, which itself may generate lots of output

System.out.println(count);    // output the same value again
System.out.println("Hello."); // output another string
```

So, unless the value passed to the method is `0`, every call to the method will produce four lines of output:

- the number that was passed to it
- a string
- the number that was passed to it again
- another string

So for any call to the method where you don't pass the value `0`, you should expect to see the value that you do pass to it output twice.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was really helpful! It just confused me a bit but now I see that I was just overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `count` is neither incrementing or decrementing inside the method. The variable is assigned to the value of `i` in the first line of your method. It stays at that value **for that specific method invocation**. This means when you call `sayHi(4)` you are executing the following pseudo code:

```
public static void sayHi(4) {
    int count = 4;
    System.out.println(4);
    if(4 == 0) return; // which is "false"


    System.out.println("hi!");
    sayHi(3); // 4 - 1

    System.out.println(4);

    System.out.println("Hello.");

}
```

So at the start and at the end, the value `4` is printed, as you have such two `println()` statements (and you don't exit the method early at the `if()` statement). Due to the recursion, at some point you are calling `sayHi(0)`, which result in the following pseudo code execution:

```
public static void sayHi(0) {
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println(0);
    if(0 == 0) return; // which is "true"


    System.out.println("hi!");
    sayHi(-1); // 0 - 1

    System.out.println(0);

    System.out.println("Hello.");
}
```

There are two `println(0);` calls, but since the `if()` condition is met, this method exits at that location early and the second `println()` statement isn't executed at all. That's why you have only one `0` printed in your output.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, I see how recursion works now!

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm learning about recursion ..."*

Here are some note-worthy texts.

The following book, by *[No Starch Press Publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Starch_Press)*, has some excellent examples of recursion, using *[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)*, and *[Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language))*.
*[No Starch Press Publishing – The Recursive Book of Recursion](https://nostarch.com/recursive-book-recursion)*.

Additionally, *Wikipedia* provides a great article, covering the topic of *recursion* in *computer science*.
*[Wikipedia – Recursion (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))*.

> *"... Why is the count incrementing after the count was already set at 0? Is it going back to its original value after terminating the recursion? ..."*

Utilize the *[String#indent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indent(int))* method, to accent the stacking order of each *call*.
You can presume a *[LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))* order; which is *"last-in, first-out"*, meaning, the most recently added value, is the first to be removed.
Like a stack of plates at a buffet, to paraphrase.

Here is an example.
We'll decrease *i*, and increase *x*.

On *call 4*, where *i* is *0*, we return, arriving after the invocation of *call 3*, and print *i*, *"after, i = 1"*.

```java
void f(int i, int x) {
    System.out.print(("call " + x).indent(x));
    System.out.print(("before, i = " + i).indent(x));
    if (i == 0) return;
    f(i - 1, x + 1);
    System.out.print(("call " + x).indent(x));
    System.out.print(("after, i = " + i).indent(x));
}
```

Output

```
call 0
before, i = 4
 call 1
 before, i = 3
  call 2
  before, i = 2
   call 3
   before, i = 1
    call 4
    before, i = 0
   call 3
   after, i = 1
  call 2
  after, i = 2
 call 1
 after, i = 3
call 0
after, i = 4
```